# Can't pass a javascript variable to a php tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to display a javascript variable in the tag in the HTML page but it doesn't appear when I click the button. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

HTML

```
<button name = "presser">go </button>
<p id = "display"></p>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "processor_file.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
$(":button").click(function(){
    $.get("middleman.php", {theword: "happen"},function(data,status){
        $.getElementById("display").innerHTML = data;
    });
});
```

PHP code from middleman.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["theword"])){
        $token = $_GET["theword"];
        echo substr($token, 1, 3);
    }
?>
```

The word is successfully passed to the javascript page from the php page but when I try to display it through the `<p>` tag, nothing happens.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? Like something saying that `$.getElementById` is not a function?

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing vanilla js and jquery, you should do as follows:

```
$(":button").click(function(){
    $.get("middleman.php", {theword: "happen"},function(data,status){
        $("#display").html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`. Or use the jQuery function

```
$("#display").html(data);
```